# How to convert a string with commas to a string with hashtags - ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to convert a string with commas to a string with hashtags. Could anyone please help?

What I tried so far is below. It gives individual elements when used `map`. How do i make it a single string with `#` appended before each item in the array.

```js
const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';

const splitArray = tags.split(",").map(val=> console.log('#'+val));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.join('')`:

```js
const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';

const result = tags.split(",").map(val=> "#"+val).join('');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead with global and extend with `#` in the beginning.

Extend with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), using `#` in the first character's place:

```js
const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';
const result = `#${tags.replace(/,/g, '#')}`;
console.log(result);
```

Or as Patrick suggested in the comment section with `/^|,/g` in the RegExp:

```js
const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';
const result = tags.replace(/^|,/g, '#');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It won't add the `#` character to the first item

Answer (score 1):

Using **Reduce**.

```js
const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';

const splitArray = tags.split(",").reduce( (res,val) => (res+'#'+val) ,'');
console.log(splitArray);
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, i have updated the answer with reduce. Please upvote it if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 0):

I believe that basic replace will make it faster.
Check this:

```
 const tags = 'caramel,vanilla,chocolate';

 var hastags = (tags, sp) => {
     return typeof tags === "string" && tags.trim() ? "#" + tags.replace(sp || ",", "#") : "";
 };

 console.log(hastags(tags, ","));
```